# Subquery result as function parameter

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, subquery

I have two tables:

- Entities: | **id** UNSIGNED INT | **pos** POINT | ... |
- Relations: | **id** UNSIGNED INT | **srcId** UNSIGNED INT | **dstId** UNSIGNED INT | ... |

Columns **id** in both tables are primary keys.

Columns **srcId** and **dstId** of Relation are references (foreign key) to Entities **id** column.

I am trying to make a procedure that will select all Relations where either of following is true:

1. **srcId** Entity is inside of newRect and outside of oldRect AND
   **dstId** Entity is inside of newRect and outside of oldRect
2. **srcId** Entity is inside of newRect and outside of oldRect AND
   **dstId** Entity is outside of newRect and outside of oldRect
3. **srcId** Entity is outside of newRect and outside of oldRect AND
   **dstId** Entity is inside of newRect and outside of oldRect

```
DECLARE oldRect DEFAULT ENVELOPE(LINESTRING(POINT(0, 0), POINT(500, 500)));
DECLARE newRect DEFAULT ENVELOPE(LINESTRING(POINT(0, 0), POINT(1000, 1000)));

SELECT DISTINCT r.*
FROM Entities AS e
JOIN Relations AS r ON e.id IN (r.srcId, r.dstId)
WHERE
    ST_CONTAINS(newRect,
        SELECT re.pos
        FROM Entities AS re
        WHERE re.id = srcId
    )
AND NOT
    ST_CONTAINS(oldRect,
        SELECT re.pos
        FROM Entities AS re
        WHERE re.id = srcId
    )
AND
    ST_CONTAINS(newRect,
        SELECT re.pos
        FROM Entities AS re
        WHERE re.id = dstId
    )
AND NOT
    ST_CONTAINS(oldRect,
        SELECT re.pos
        FROM Entities AS re
        WHERE re.id = dstId
    )
.... ?;
```

EDIT: I figured out a way, am wondering if there is any better. If I create a new function and call that function.

```
CREATE FUNCTION getPos(id INT UNSIGNED) RETURNS POINT
BEGIN
    DECLARE pos POINT DEFAULT NULL;
    SELECT re.pos INTO pos
    FROM Entities AS re
    WHERE re.id = id;
RETURN pos;
END
```

Comment: Any subquery needs parentheses around it.

Comment: You need an `OR` operator between the 3 different conditions, not `AND`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Bill says, subqueries must always be enclosed in parentheses.

But there's no point in doing `select...from Entities e...join Relations` when you don't appear to use `e` at all.  You should `select...from Relations`.  And if you join Entities twice (once for src, once for dst) you don't need subqueries at all.  Then DISTINCT isn't needed, since you will only have one possible row per Relations row.

And your logic seems to boil down to:

```
dstId Entity is outside of oldRect
AND
srcId Entity is outside of oldRect
AND
(
    srcId Entity is inside of newRect
    OR
    dstId Entity is inside of newRect
)
```

So:

```
select r.*
from Relations r
join Entities se on se.id=r.srcId
join Entities de on de.id=r.dstId
where
    not st_contains(oldRect, de.pos)
    and not st_contains(oldRect, se.pos)
    and (
        st_contains(newRect, se.pos)
        or st_contains(newRect, de.pos)
    )
```